# Remove element from list without side-effect

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How do I remove a specific index from a list without side-effect? That is, using:

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
del L[2]
```

is not an alternative, as I still want to keep `L` intact. Is there a neater way than doing a deep copy and then remove the value from there?

Comment: What do you mean by _without side-effect_? When is `L` intact?

Comment: @Finwood "Without side-effect" = I want another list besides L, that contains all the values but some index (in the case of the example, `2`). L must be preserved after the operation.

Comment: Your question is an [oxymoron](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oxymoron).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slice the list:

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
L[:2] + L[3:]
```

---

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

If a deep copy is what you want, then I would suggest

```
import copy

copy.deepcopy(L[:i]) + copy.deepcopy(L[i+1:])
```

where `i` is the index you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list without the to-be-deleted value in it.

If you want to remove specific index/ indices.

```
>> [x for index,x in enumerate(L) if index != 2]
[1, 2, 4]
```

Or,

```
>> [L[i] for i in xrange(len(L)) if i != 2]
[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: The OP wants to remove the element at index `2`, not an element having a value `3`. You should update your post to answer the OP's question (he explicitely specified it at the beginning of his post).